# Angular Initialising an array and populating with numbers based on another $scopes.length

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I want to dynamically create an array of numbered objects
`$scope.answers [];`
based on the length of another `$scope` e.g. `$scope.myQuestions.length`   been the numbered of answers

so if the `$scope.myQuestions.length` was 5 the result would be

```
     [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

       Ref:  http://2ality.com/2013/11/initializing-arrays.html
      This is how it's done in Javascript just need it juxtaposing into     Angular

     Array(undefined, undefined, undefined)
    Array.apply(null, Array(3))
   If we combine this trick with map(), we get what we wanted:
       function fillArrayWithNumbers(n) {
    var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(n));
    return arr.map(function (x, i) { return i });
   }
   The function in action:
      > fillArrayWithNumbers(5)
         [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. AngularJS, as its name indicates, uses JavaScript.

Comment: I've had a go to no avail   with  $scope.answers = function (empId) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myQuestions.length; i++) {
                        if ($scope.myQuestions[i].id === empId) {
                            return $scope.myQuestions[i].$index;
                        }
                    };
                };

Comment: Edit your question and post what you tried, properly formatted, in the question. Explain clearly what you want to achieve. Your code uses empId, checks the ID of questions, etc., although your explanation currently says that t should just create an array containing numbers from 0 to the length of myQuestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.length = parseInt($scope.edition_products.length);

            $scope.quizAnswers = [];

                   for(var i = 0 ; i < parseInt($scope.length) ; i++)
                    $scope.quizAnswers.push({id:i, Index:i,  "Answered":"No","Correct":"null"});   worked for me
```

Comment: You can even only do like this ```
 for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.edition_products.length ; i++){
     $scope.quizAnswers.push( {id:i, Index:i, "Answered":"No", "Correct":"null" }); 
} ``` No need to add new variable to calculate `length`